# Unhashable type 'list' while looping through dataframe in Python

Tags: python, nlp, pandas, dataframe, python-3.x

I have the following dataframe `comments`. I have segregated a list of users based on certain conditions. I want to get the count of words based on those users which are named as `gold_users`. But I am getting an error in my code `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`. Please help me fix this.

**DataFrame(comments)**

```
       Id|                    Text                             |    UserId  
        6|  [2006, course, allen, knutsons, 2001, course, ...  |    3   
        8|  [also, theo, johnsonfreyd, note, mark, haimans...  |    1
```

**Code**

```
for index,rows in comments.iterrows():
  gold_comments = rows[comments.Text.loc[comments.UserId.isin(gold_users)]]
  Counter(gold_comments)
```

**Expected Output**

```
#Top 10 Words that appear the most in the comments made by gold users with their count.
 [['scholar',20],['school',18],['bus',15],['class',14],['teacher',14],['bell',13],['time',12],['books',11],['bag',9],'student',7]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'.
```

You will get this error when you are trying to put list as key in dictionary or set because list is unhashable object.

Example you trying to input code such as

```
dict1 ={ 1:'one', [2]:'two'}
print(dict1)

O/p:
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-73-c4e2fd1e6bf0> in <module>
----> 1 dict1 ={ 1:'one', [2]:'two'}
      2 print(dict1)
 
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

solution :
Try to convert the list into tuple

Hashable object in Python:

- int
- float
- decimal
- bool
- string
- tuple
- complex
- range
- frozenset
- bytes

UnHashable object in Python

- list
- set
- dict
- bytearray
- customclasses